# Sumar elementos de un array

Tags: javascript

Tengo el problema que me piden que haga una función `cantidadDeMesesConGanancias` que me sume los elementos positivos ...
Yo hago ...

```
Function cantidadDeMesesConGanancias(meses){
Var sumatoria=0
For(Var i=0;i <meses.length;i++){
If(meses[i] ›0){
Sumatoria=sumatoria+meses
}
}
Return sumatoria}
```

Y me pone error

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo primero que tenes que decirnos.. es que error te da...

Comment: Con ánimo de contribuir, me permito hacer un aporte a lo dicho por el amigo Juan Salvador, con su permiso. JavaScrip distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, por lo que escribir un nombre de variable usando mayúsculas y minúsculas no es intrínsecamente errado, el error radica en escribirlo de una forma en unos casos y de otra forma en otros casos, javascript lo tomará como dos variables distintas.

Answer (score 4):

Hay muchos errores en tu código.

- Las palabras reservadas **function**, **var**, **for**, **if** y **return** deben ir completamente en minúsculas.
- En la linea 5 de tu código, la variable **sumatoria** debe ir en minúsculas.
- También en la linea 5, estás sumando la variable **sumatoria** y **meses** cuando deberías sumar **sumatoria** y 1.

Al final tu código debe quedar así: (ya identado correctamente)

```
function cantidadDeMesesConGanancias(meses) {
    var sumatoria = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < meses.length; i++ ) {
        if ( meses[i] > 0 ) {
            sumatoria = sumatoria + 1;
        }
    }
    return sumatoria;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En cualquiera que sea el lenguaje de programación hay que procurar usar la notacion camelCase en la definicion de variables y funciones.
Por otra parte Javascript como todo lenguaje tiene un set de palabras reservadas 
[MDN Palabras reservadas javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Palabras_Reservadas)

al final el codigo debe quedarte asi:

```
function cantidadDeMesesConGanancias(meses) {
var sumatoria = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < meses.length; i++ ) {
    if ( meses[i] > 0 ) {
        sumatoria++;
    }
}
return sumatoria; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Porque haces esto:

```
Sumatoria=sumatoria+meses;
```

Debería ser:

```
sumatoria=sumatoria+1;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero es importante leer [answer]  para realizar respuestas en el sitio.